# How do I automatically add all existing apps to my home screen?

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie, home-screen, motorola, app-drawer

When I got my first smart phone years ago, there was no app drawer. Every app I had was represented as one button in one app menu, so I didn't have to look in two places if I couldn't find an app. To me this was ideal, but now that I use Android phones I have to deal with both the app drawer and the home screen.

I just got a new Moto g7 Power (Android 9 "Pie") and backed it up from my old Android phone, so there are over a hundred apps on it. I want all of my apps to show up on the home screen so that there aren't apps lurking in the app drawer that I can just forget about, and so that the apps I want to use are easier to access. Is there any way I can automatically add all of my apps from the app drawer onto the home screen so that I don't have to manually hold and drag over a hundred apps one after another? It's fine if they don't automatically get sorted into folders etc. because I'm happy to do that myself.

When I looked up my question in the Play Store, I found an app called Smart Drawer but it's not even smart enough to know what a game is. Are there any other apps I should try?

It's maddening that it's so hard to find information about this. I would have expected this to be an extremely common thing for Android users to want to do.

Comment: Use an launcher app that imitates the behavior of an iPhone (on iPhones all apps are always shown on the home screens): search Google PlayStore for [launcher iphone](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher%20iphone&c=apps)

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I tried the first one and it worked, though the apps were invisible until I restarted. I'll see how it goes: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xos.iphonex.iphone.applelauncher

Comment: I want to mention that the iPhone launcher is not ideal so I'm still looking for solutions. The main problem is that I don't want to have to continuously use a whole new environment. I want the equivalent of moving the apps out of my app drawer manually, but I want it done automatically. It would be nice to have a run-and-done action rather than an ongoing process.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. I guess my idea of a "home screen" is specific to any given launcher. If there's no way to do this without regard to the launcher, is it possible to automatically add all existing apps to the home screen in Moto App Launcher specifically?

Comment: @beeshyams - I think I might as well accept that as an answer, if you mention that the functionality isn't available in most launchers. As an Android user, what do you do with a bunch of pre-installed apps in your app drawer? Do you manually add every app to your home screen or do you just leave the apps off your home screen and access them some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android launcher(s) is a dedicated app that serves as an UI to the underlying OS. There are tons of launchers available with features catering to the tastes of needs of users. If one needs features to be added to the existing (OEM or third party), they **cannot** be provided by yet another app because the launcher is so closely tied with the Android OS. Either the developer of the launcher, provides the requested feature or one uses a different launcher with that feature.

Case in point is the requirement of OP to add all installed apps with the OEM Moto launcher (instead of having
 installed apps in the app drawer). OP is looking for the functionality of [ABC launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artarmin.launcher) to be added to Moto launcher. This **isn't possible** for reasons explained.

Android users, usually, let pre and subsequently installed apps be in the app drawer and choose the apps, they access more frequently on home screen, organized in the manner of their choice. Launchers let you search for  apps, even when they are not on home screen. In the app drawer, they may be sorted alphabetically, or organized by functions (e.g.games) or user created panes (e.g. shopping /banking apps) etc. The possibilities are endless and there are launchers available for different needs. [Nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) is famous for exactly this - letting the user customize practically each element of the launcher interface (the reason I use it)

**tl:dr;** You choose the launcher that works best for you

Comment: ABC Launcher does not allow you to make folders, I think. Also, the functionality of having only a home screen and no app drawer (which would be a persistent state) is different from the functionality of automating the process of adding all apps from the app drawer to your home screen (which would be a one-time action).

Comment: TBH, I didn't test ABC for all features. Was concentrating on all apps on home screen aspect // I get the distinction you are making regarding adding apps to home screen but I don't think it is feasible for the same reason of a launcher being so closely integrated with Android OS. Thanks for accepting